# How can I include the doc_id field in results returned by Google App Engine search?

Tags: gae-search

I have a set of fields indexed by GAE search and can get results thus:

```
options = search.QueryOptions(returned_fields=['ID', 'firstname', 'lastname']}
query = search.Query('firstname:moe')
```

This gets me results returned and I can access data in the two name fields. But ID isn't included. I've tried 'doc_id" as well.

How can I get each doc ID with each result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc_id isn't "just another field"; it's a separate attribute of the Document object.  Try like this:

```
search_results = index.search(query);
for doc in search_result.results:
    d = doc.doc_id
```